# How to get an estimate and confidence interval for a contrast in R with offset

Tags: r, glm

I've got a Poisson GLM model fitted in R, looking something like this:

```
glm(Outcome~Exposure + Var1 + offset(log(persontime)),family=poisson,data=G))
```

Where Outcome will end up being a rate, the Exposure is a continuous variable, and Var1 is a factor with three levels.

It's easy enough from the output of that:

```
    Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.6998     0.1963 -29.029  < 2e-16
Exposure       4.7482     1.0793   4.399 1.09e-05
Var1Thing1    -0.2930     0.2008  -1.459 0.144524    
Var1Thin       1.0395     0.2037   5.103 3.34e-07
Var1Thing3     0.7722     0.2201   3.508 0.000451
```

To get the estimate of a one-unit increase in Exposure. But a one-unit increase isn't actually particularly meaningful. An increase of 0.025 is actually far more likely. Getting an estimate for *that* isn't particularly difficult either, but I'd like a confidence interval along with the estimate. My intuition is that I need to use the contrast package, but the following generated an error:

```
diff <- contrast(Fit,list(Exposure=0.030,Var1="Thing1"),list(Exposure=0.005,Type="Thing1"))
```

"Error in offset(log(persontime)) : object 'persontime' not found"

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change the scale of your predictor of interest. If a 0.025 increment is of interest just divide "exposure" by that factor, rerun and then you have a one unit increase and the associated std-error. (This is going to be "linear" so the ratio of coef to se is going to be the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use the `confint` function (which in this case will call the `MASS:::confint.glm` method), as in:

```
confint(Fit)
```

Since the standard errors is the model scale linearly with the linear changes in the scale of the variable 'Exposure' in your model, you can simply multiply the confidence interval by the difference in scale to get the confidence for a smaller 'unit' change.

Dumb example:

Lets say you want to test the hypothesis that people fall down more often when they've had more alcohol.  You test this by randomly serving individuals varying amounts of alcohol (which you measure in ml) and counting the number of times each person falls down. Your model is:

```
Fit <- glm(falls ~ alcohol_ml,data=myData, family=poisson)
```

and the coef table is

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -5.6998     0.1963 -29.029  < 2e-16
Alcohol_ml     4.7482     1.0793   4.399 1.09e-05
```

and the Confidence interval for alcohol is 4-6 (just to keep is simple).  Now a colegue asks you to give the the confidence interval in ounces.  All you have to do is to scale by the confidence interval by the conversion factor (29.5735 ounces per ml), as in:

```
c(4,6) * 29.5735 # effect per ounce alcohol [notice multiplication is used to rescale here]
```

alternatively you could re-scale your data and re-fit the model:

```
mydata$alcohol_oz <- mydata$alcohol_ml / 29.5735 #[notice division is used to rescale here]
Fit <- glm(falls ~ alcohol_oz,data=myData, family=poisson)
```

or you could re-scale your data right in the model:

```
#[again notice that division is used here]
Fit <- glm(falls ~ I(alcohol_ml/29.5735),data=myData, family=poisson)
```

Either way, you will get the same confidence intervals on the new scale.

Back to your example: if you're units of `Exposure` are so large that you are unlikely to observe such a change within an individual and a smaller change is more easily interpreted, just re-scale your variable 'Exposure' (as in `myData$Exposure_newScale = myData$Exposure / 0.030` so `Exposure_newScale` is in multiples of `0.030`) or rescale the confidence intervals using either of these methods.

Comment: confint will give me the confidence intervals for the estimate, which exponentiated will give me the confidence intervals for a one-unit increase. With the estimate I could say take exp(estimate*0.025) to get what I wanted, but can I do that with the confidence intervals? I've always hated contrasts...

Comment: Hmm.. I'll think on that.  I have to run now, though

Comment: I extended the answer based on the assumption that your problem with the  regression `fit` was that a one unit change in the variable `Exposure` was too large to be interpretable.